# link button has an underline that cannot be removed, and icon turns red when clicked

Tags: html, css

I made a "button" well... not really, I made a link that redirects the user to my 'whatever' page or whatever.
problem is, it has an annoyying underline that cannot be removed even when i try puttin in CSS text-decoration: none;
why is it happening?
how can i remove it?
also, whenever i click on the button, the LinkedIn icon turns red.. the button is purple and it makes it ugly.. how can i remove the red color when clicked?
when i am hovering next to the box in the 'peticide' chrome extention, i noticed a red line is it related somehow?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.title h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 860px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;

  /* !!!! !!!! Styling the text and giving it gradient *מדרון* !!!! !!!!*/
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /* Make sure text is infront of background images */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {  
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 10000px 0;
  }
}

.stars,
.twinkling,
.clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}

.clouds {
  background: transparent url(clouds.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.4;
  animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 {
  font-size: 63px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 705px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 span {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 28px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff, 0 0 80px #fff,
    0 0 120px #fff;
}
table,
tr,
td,
th{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.tabledata{
top: 400px;
left: 231px;
width: 1200px;
height: 550px;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;

}
.button{
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  top: 896px;
  left: 1233px;
  width: 248px;
  height: 46px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "consolas", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1.7s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover
{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffffff, 0 0 40px #ffffff, 0 0 80px #ffffff;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}



.secondaryButton{
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  top: 896px;
  left: 236px;
  width: 197px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "consolas", sans-serif;
  -webki
```

```html
<div class="button">
          <a href="/project2/contact.html">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          contact me
          </div>
          <div class="secondaryButton">
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah-blah/">
                  <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              linkedIn<ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the CSS of your tag like this

For example:

```
<a href='xyx.com' class='style'>
```

CSS

```
.style{
text-decoration:none
 }
```

Comment: One of the simplest answer that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

your underline is on a link so you have to remove text-decoratuon on a tag. then on a tag :focus change your color. Look at code below if thats help you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.title h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 860px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;

  /* !!!! !!!! Styling the text and giving it gradient *מדרון* !!!! !!!!*/
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /* Make sure text is infront of background images */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {  
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 10000px 0;
  }
}

.stars,
.twinkling,
.clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}

.clouds {
  background: transparent url(clouds.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.4;
  animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 {
  font-size: 63px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 705px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 span {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 28px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff, 0 0 80px #fff,
    0 0 120px #fff;
}
table,
tr,
td,
th{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.tabledata{
top: 400px;
left: 231px;
width: 1200px;
height: 550px;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;

}
.button{
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  top: 896px;
  left: 1233px;
  width: 248px;
  height: 46px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "consolas", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1.7s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button a, .secondaryButton a {text-decoration: none; }

 a:focus {color: gray;}

.button:hover
{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffffff, 0 0 40px #ffffff, 0 0 80px #ffffff;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}



.secondaryButton{
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 236px;
  width: 197px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "consolas", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1.7s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.secondaryButton:hover
{
  color:  rgb(165, 70, 254);
  background: rgb(188, 123, 248);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px  rgb(165, 70, 254), 0 0 40px  rgb(165, 70, 254), 0 0 80px  rgb(165, 70, 254);
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
          <a href="/project2/contact.html">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          contact me</a>
          </div>
          <div class="secondaryButton">
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah-blah/">
                  <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              linkedIn<ion-social-icon name="logo-linkedin">
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your child selector `a` to the button classes so your button classes are targeting the anchor element...

```
.button a{
...
}

.button a:hover
{
...
}

.secondaryButton a{
...
}
```

A better solution is to remove the div wrappers and move your class into the anchor tag directly and also beef up your anchor CSS selectors with pseudo-classes as shown below so you have more granular control of your links.

```
.button,
.button:link,
.button:visited,
.button:focus,
.button:active{
...
}

.button:hover
{
...
}

.secondaryButton,
.secondaryButton:link,
.secondaryButton:visited,
.secondaryButton:hover,
.secondaryButton:focus,
.secondaryButton:active{
...
}


<a class="button" href="/project2/contact.html">contact me</a>
<a class="secondaryButton" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah-blah/">linkedIn</a>

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.title h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 860px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;

  /* !!!! !!!! Styling the text and giving it gradient *מדרון* !!!! !!!!*/
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /* Make sure text is infront of background images */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {  
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 10000px 0;
  }
}

.stars,
.twinkling,
.clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}

.clouds {
  background: transparent url(clouds.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.4;
  animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 {
  font-size: 63px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 705px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 span {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 28px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff, 0 0 80px #fff,
    0 0 120px #fff;
}
table,
tr,
td,
th{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.tabledata{
top: 400px;
left: 231px;
width: 1200px;
height: 550px;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;

}
.button{
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  top: 896px;
  left: 1233px;
  width: 248px;
  height: 46px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "consolas", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1.7s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover
{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ffffff, 0 0 40px #ffffff, 0 0 80px #ffffff;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

   .button a{
 text-decoration : none;`
}




.secondaryButton{
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  top: 896px;
  left: 236px;
  width: 197px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  font-family: "consolas", sans-serif;
  -webki
  
  
  /* remove the underline and red color when the button is clicked */
    /* .button > a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button > a:focus{
        color: black;
    }
    .secondaryButton > a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .secondaryButton > a:focus{
        color: black;
    } */
```

```html
<div class="button">
          <a href="/project2/contact.html">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          contact me
          </div>
          <div class="secondaryButton">
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/blah-blah/">
                  <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              linkedIn<ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
              </div>
              
   <!-- I suggest like this to make a button or link, just style it -->
    <!-- <div class="button">
        <a href="">Contact me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="secondaryButton">
        <a href="">LinkedIn</a>
    </div> -->
```

I suggest that if you create a button it's better to use the `<button></button>` tag, if you want to remove the underline, give the `<a>` element a style `text-decoration:none`,and your `<a>` tag has no closing tag  `</a>`